# Unit Testing React Native: NativeModules.RNViewShot is undefined. Make sure the library is linked on the native side

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I keep getting this annoying warning when I run some of my unit tests on various components in my app:

```
NativeModules.RNViewShot is undefined. Make sure the library is linked on the native side.
```

In my root dir, I run `'react-native link'` and I see this in the console:

```
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-view-shot is already linked
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-view-shot is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

What gives here > ?

```
Platform: MacOS,
Editor: VSCode,
react: "16.4.0",
react-native: "0.54.2",
react-native-view-shot: "^2.4.0",
```

Comment: Is it working on the dev build? or else try linking manually.

Comment: Works in dev build fine only gives warning in unit tests only.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make a mock for this library.

E.g.

1. Create a directory **__mocks**__ in **app**
2. Create a file **react-native-view-shot.js**
3. In the file, add the following:

   ```
   jest.mock('react-native-view-shot', () => {
     return {
       // whatever function you want to mock, e.g capture: jest.fn()
     };
   });
   ```

Comment: I am doing this. My __mocks__ folder is inside the __tests__ folder

Comment: Try adding it in the *app* folder instead and see if it helps